# Show/Hide content based on anchor - Almost there

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am very close but just can't see what I am missing in the `jQuery` script to only display the correct block of content based upon the anchor clicked and want to display initially to a visitor the first block of content from the anchors. Any help is appreciated.

I have dynamically generated anchor links with a class of `.link`

The content is also dynamically generated and each anchor point (A, B, C...) has it's content contained in a `ul` class of `.test-full-list`. Any help is appreciated.

**Generated content:**

***Anchor links:***

```
<span class="link"><a href="#A">A</a></span>
<span class="link"><a href="#B">B</a></span>
```

**Content:**

```
<div class="test-listing-container">
    <ul class="test-full-list">
        <ul class="test-category-list"> 
            <a name="A"></a>
            <div class="anchor-header">- A -</div>
            <li id=test-list> 
                <a href="some link" class="main" title="some title">Some Link 1</a>
                <a href="some link" class="main" title="some title">Some Link 1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.test-listing-container').hide();

    jQuery('.link a').click(function () {
        var jQuerydiv = jQuery('.test-full-list').eq(jQuery(this).index('.link a'));
        jQuerydiv.show('.test-full-list'); // show the relevant div
    });
});
```

Comment: for one you are mixing the elements, you have anchor and div elements inside a ul tag, they need to either be in the li tag or outside the whole ul

Comment: It looks like you're hiding the parent container for all the ul items as soon as the doc is ready? wouldn't all the children be hidden as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Adding a fiddle to demo the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Fm6bR/1/

Assuming you can't change the markup slightly, you may do the following
    A
    B

```
<div class="test-listing-container">
    <ul class="test-full-list">
      <ul class="test-category-list">
        <a name="A"></a>
        <div class="anchor-header">- A -</div>
           <li id=test-list>
           <a href="some link" class="main" title="some title">Some Link 1</a>
           <a href="some link" class="main" title="some title">Some Link 1</a>
           </li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
</div>


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('ul.test-category-list').hide();
    jQuery('ul.test-category-list').first().show(); //show the first one by default

    jQuery(document).on('click', '.link a', function (evt) {
        var $a = jQuery(evt.currentTarget),
            name = $a.attr('href').substr(1),
            $a2 = jQuery('.test-listing-container').find('a[name="' + name + '"]'),
            $ul = $a2.parents('ul.test-category-list').first();

        jQuery('ul.test-category-list').hide(); // hide all 
        $ul.show(); // show the relevant one
    });
});
```

Comment: This seems to be the route I want to go right now. The anchor header's are also dynamically generated with the list of links. The script above displays only the first grouping of listings which is great but when I click on other anchor letters nothing shows up. And I don't receive any errors in the error logs. I changed your $ to jQuery for all of them. Working on noConflict.

Comment: I have added a link to a jsfiddle. Could you please modify that to show what is not working? Secondly, the `$` in my code sample has nothing to do with `jQuery`. Its just a convention I am following to denote that the variable contains a jquery element. You DON'T need to replace it with `jQuery` in the code above or in the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Amith. I too put it in jsfiddle. Your script works fine. It is my HTML rendering of the php. I am not getting an enclosing </ul> tag after the test category list. Will have to work on that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If you're bringing in content dynamically, your `.click()` will not work. This is because the element you are trying to attach the click to hasn't been generated.

You can replace this:

```
jQuery('.link a').click(function() {
```

With this:

```
jQuery('.test-listing-container').on('click', '.link a', function() {
```

If that doesn't work:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.link a', function() {
```

Comment: Simplify, add a special class or ID on the div header and just grab the  on click event on that element.  No need for an <a> tag.

Comment: @KnowHowSolutions You won't be able to get the hash from the clicked a tag if you do it like that.

Comment: You don't really need the href.  I was just pointing it out.  See Patrick's solution.

Comment: Patrick's solution uses the `.link a` as well. Is that not what you were referring to?

Comment: I get what you're saying and yes in theory you don't need the href. Since the OP included it in his HTML there's probably a reason for it. That's why I included it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the content with an id based on the anchor name or some other unique identifer of the content. set data-content on each link to the id of the contents id. then use jquery to get the content by using `.data` function on the link in the click function

HTML

```
<span class="link"><a href="#fulllistA" data-content="fulllistA">A</a></span>
<span class="link"><a href="#fulllistB" data-content="fulllistB">B</a></span>
<div class="test-listing-container">
   <ul class="test-full-list" id="fulllistA">
     <ul class="test-category-list">
          <li id=test-list>
          <a href="some link" class="main" title="some title">Some Link 1</a>
          <a href="some link" class="main" title="some title">Some Link 1</a>
          </li>
     </ul>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".link a",function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   var content = jQuery("#"+jQuery(this).data("content"));
   jQuery(".test-listing-container > ul").not(content).hide(); // hide the others.
   content.show();  
});
```